# How to parsing in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I made an application which has an Activity that parses a XML file (XMLPullParser) and shows data in a Listview. It works.
In the same application I have another Activity in which I put different fragments in dependece of the selected item of the Navigation Drawer.
Now, my question is: how can I use the data, obtained in the Parsing activity, and manage them inside a fragment?

Comment: Can you post your the code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to send the whole parsed data to the fragment.

You can write an own `Handler` or `Manager` class to parse the file for you and keep it in the memory (It can be some Singleton stuff). Once you parsed it you just have to pass the ID of the item and the `Fragment` can get it out from your `Handler`.

You can pass whatever you like to the `Fragment` like this:

```
public static YourFragment newInstance(int index) {
    YourFragment f = new YourFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("index", index);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

//To get out
//...
Bundle args = getArguments();
int index = args.getInt("index", 0);
//...
```

Comment: Thank you GaborNovak for your quick answer. So I already have my XMLPullParserHandler. So, if I correctly got it, I add the code you posted inside my handler. to pass data to my fragment. what if I want to pass a whole adapter or a list (created in the parser activity) to my fragment? do I have to change the parameter int index with an adapter? thank you

Comment: I think it would be easier to implement a custom `Manager` class which is able to parse the xml. It's not a good thing to parse xml inside an `Activity`. Once you parsed in a different class you are able to keep it in memory off the `MainActivity`, and pass only an index to your `Fragment`.